# Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.MarkupExtensions.CompiledBindingExtension to type Avalonia.Data.Binding'

Tags: c#, avalonia

Имею вот такое в axaml

```
<DataGrid.Columns >
    DataGridTextColumn Tag="shets" Width="90" Header="Счет" 
                       Binding="{Binding shets}" 
                       CanUserSort="True" Foreground="Black"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Tag="name" Width="570" Header="Наименование"  
                        Binding="{Binding name}" CanUserSort="True"
                        Foreground="Black"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Хочу получить Binding

```
    var ff  = (DataGridTextColumn)this.list1.Columns[sortcolumn];
    gg = (Binding)ff.Binding;
```

и получаю ошибку

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.MarkupExtensions.CompiledBindingExtension'  to
> type 'Avalonia.Data.Binding'.

Как их сконвертировать и желательно в
`Avalonia.Data.Binding` потому что если я колонки создаю вручную то там
`Avalonia.Data.Binding` и все работает.

Comment: А зачем Вам это? Может основная проблема в чём-то другом и Вы ищете сложный путь для её решения

Comment: @Cost странный вопрос , а вам зачем зачем это мне ? Есть несоответствие между созданным в axaml и кодом это вызывает вопросы к авалонии . Ей доверять просто нельзя и перечень пользователей это просто филькина грамота .

Comment: Нечасто видел сценарий когда нужен сам экземпляр класса `Binding` в явном виде. Обычно достаточно источника и цели

Comment: Так и мне не нужен этот binding . Мне нужен  Path из него и как его получить ?

Comment: А зачем `Path`? Если хотите узнать какая из колонок обновилась, то это легче обработать со стороны VM

Comment: Мне нужно это для поиска или фильтра по колонке которую пользователь отсортировал . Можно у DataGridTextColumn занести в Tag к которому доступ простой но это лишнее движение а мне в лом .

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151157/discussion-between-bob-and-cost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в скомпилированных привязках . Авалония не может скомпилированный биндинг вытащить обратно или для этого нужен конвертер которые я еще не копал . Вот здесь подробно https://avaloniaui.homesoft.ru/docs/contents/data-binding/compiledbindings/
а мое решенние <DataGridTextColumn x:CompileBindings="False"..... а для всего окна x:CompileBindings="True" как и было.